# TCP-Server wont print/receive data from remote client

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am facing a strange problem,
**local** client tcp-connections (python) to my tcp-server (java, on windows 8 64-bit) are working. For example

Python client.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.2.108", 30000))
s.sendall('Hello, server')
s.close()
```

successfully connects to 192.168.2.108 at port 30000, and the server prints "Hello, server" on eclipse's console.

If I change the interface to loopback interface, it works too.

If I use the same script on my **remote** Linux machine (Arch with 3.18.6 kernel, 32-bit, ip: 192.168.2.104) the server won't print out anything.

If I try to connect via `nc 192.168.2.108 30000` on my client -> same problem

If I try to connect via `telnet 192.168.2.108 30000` on my client -> same problem (telnet: connection timed out)

Here a piece of code which might be important for the problem.
The backstory is, the server creates 3 serverSockets with ports 30000, 40000, 50000 each in its own thread.

TCP.java

```
[...]

// pseudo-code: List<ServerSocket> serverSockets = {serverSocket1 port 30000,   
// serverSocket2 port 40000, serverSocket3 port 50000}

[...]

for(ServerSocket serverSocket : serverSockets){
new Thread(new TCPRunnable(serverSocket)).start();
}

[...]
```

TCPRunnable.java

```
[...]

public TCPRunnable(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
}

public void run() {
    long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    System.out.println(threadId + ": " + serverSocket);
    // output: 20: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=30000]
    try {
        System.out.println("before accept()");

        while(true){
            System.out.println("before accept() in while-loop");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            String message = readMessage(socket);
            System.out.println(threadId + ": " + message );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("leaving run");
}

[...]
```

output of `netstat -a | find "30000" to see that the port(s) are listening

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:30000          be-dsktp:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:30000             be-dsktp:0             LISTENING
```

I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you have firewall on the way?

Comment: Your question title implies that the server receives the data but does not print it.  Your description of the problem, however, indicates that the client is unable to connect to the server at all.  As @Zielu already observed, this sounds like a firewall issue.  You'll need to configure the server machine's firewall to allow incoming TCP traffic on port 30000.

Comment: oh common, i spent 20 minutes to make this post... i allowed eclipse.exe but switching off the firewall did it -.-. yeah the title is misleading sorry

Comment: As a note to the solution: It's not eclipse that is listening, it is the java process spawned by eclipse that needs to be allowed through the firewall.

Comment: yeah, i thought that the server runs in eclipse's context in case of network stuff. thanks for the information

Comment: 'Title is misleading': so *fix* it.

Comment: already did it. the title does not imply that I already received the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall was in the way. javaw.exe has to be allowed in firewall.cpl.
Thanks Zielu!